# BaseVariant from " com.org.gradle.API" is deprecated in java . Wha's alternative of it?

Tags: java, android, api, gradle, junit

I  would like to use   name.capitalize from BaseVariant but it's  deprecated . What's alternative of it please ?
My environment :

```
Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.12 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
OS:           Mac OS X 11.5 x86_64
```